# Randomizing output based on a separate class JAVA

Tags: java, class, random

I have a project that utilizes two classes, the first one is a coin and it randomizes on what face it lands on after being toss, the toss method randomizes the result and the getSideUp reveals the face and is returned to the beginning. The second class, the cointoss has a goal to display the results for 30 times, keep number of each face shown and calculate and show those numbers. What I need help in is finding a way to repeat the flipping method for 30 times, each time random and different from the one before. I can calculate the number of flips, but I need to also find out how to calculate the number of "Heads" and "Tails". here are the source codes, first one being the coin class which the coin toss is based off of, and the second is the cointoss which must be repeated 30 times. How I have it so far, the result is randomized but displays the same face 30 times.

```
public class FahrDylanCoin{
private String sideUp;
public FahrDylanCoin()
{
    sideUp = "Heads";
}
public void toss(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int cToss = rand.nextInt(2);
    if (cToss == 0)
    sideUp = "Heads";
    else
    sideUp = "Tails";
}
public String getSideUp()
{
    return sideUp;
}
```

}

the second class

```
public class FahrDylanCoinToss{
public static void main (String [] args){
    FahrDylanCoin flip = new FahrDylanCoin();
    flip.toss();
    for (int i =1; i <=30; i++)
    System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + flip.getSideUp());
}
```

}

Comment: Please change your title to something useful.

Comment: If you want each of the tosses to be different, you have to put the toss inside the loop, not before it.

Comment: I see the same code twice - I do not see the code for the `FahrDylanCoin` class

Comment: fixed the duplicate codes in the question sorry about that

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have tried that, but have yet to figure it out how to do properly, there is an error saying that it needs a variable not a value and that it wont work if plugged in for i

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do the coin toss inside the for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=30; i++)
{
    flip.toss();
    System.out.println( i + "\t\t" + flip.getSideUp());
}
```

This way, the result of the coin toss is different every time. And, if you want to count the number of heads and tails, keep a value that is incremented every time it is heads, and the number of tails is then 30 - numberOfHeads.